# Combine 3 Lists with a special order after combining (using Streams)

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to combine 3 Lists in Java 8 using Streams. Achieving this is not really difficult. Following code can do this:

```
List<IntVar> combined = Stream.of(listA, listB, listC).flatMap(Collection::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Now I have the requirement that the elements of the combined list follow a simple order. The precondition is that all lists have the same size.

Imagine 3 Lists with 4 elements each:

- List A contains the elements **a1 a2 a3 a4**
- List B contains the elements **b1 b2 b3 b4**
- List C contains the elements **c1 c2 c3 c4**

The elements of the combined List should have following order:

a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3, a4, b4, c4

I think you get the idea.
Is there a way to do this in Java 8 using Streams?

Comment: Are all lists of the same size?

Comment: @KonstantinYovkov Yes, the precondition is that all lists have the same size.

Comment: can you sort after combining?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Yes I could.

Comment: could you explain expected order? 1st element from 1st list, 1st element from 2nd list and so on?

Comment: @SergeyLagutin Correct

Comment: Is the use of streams a strict requirement, and why?

Comment: @OleV.V. Not a requirement. I was just curious if this can be solved using streams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all lists are of the same size (lets call it `n`), then you could use an `IntStream` to simulate what a for-loop does:

```
List<String> x = Arrays.asList("a1", "a2", "a3");
List<String> y = Arrays.asList("b1", "b2", "b3");
List<String> z = Arrays.asList("c1", "c2", "c3");
int n = x.size();
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
IntStream.range(0, n)
         .boxed()
         .forEach(i -> { list.add(x.get(i)); 
                         list.add(y.get(i)); 
                         list.add(z.get(i)); 
                        });
```

Comment: The obligatory alternative without `forEach`/side effects: `List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, n).boxed() .flatMap(i -> Stream.of(x.get(i), y.get(i), z.get(i))) .collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: @Holger Indeed this gives `[a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2, a3, b3, c3]`.

Comment: In case you want to treat the original lists as streams too (and avoid relying on random access through `get(i)`), you may do `Iterator<String> xi = x.stream().iterator();` and similarly for y and z amd then `List<String> list = IntStream.range(0, n).boxed().flatMap(i -> Stream.of(xi.next(), yi.next(), zi.next())).collect(Collectors.toList());`. I know it’s hard to read in the comment format, though.